# public fields or C# like properties in C++?

Tags: c++

Alright so I'm trying to creating something that is sort of like the properties in C# for my classes in C++.

for example. in C# i would do this:

```
int MaxHP { get; set; }
```

or, with backing field:

```
int MaxHP 
{ 
    get { return maxHP; }
    set { maxHP = value; }
}
```

However so far with C++, I've only been able to replicate this with:

```
private:    
    int maxHP;  
    int maxEP;
public:
    int GetMaxHP() { return maxHP; }
    void UpSetMaxHP(int value){ maxHP += value; }
    void DownSetMaxHP(int value){ maxHP -= value; }
    int GetMaxEP(){ return maxEP; }
    void UpSetMaxEP(int value){ maxEP += value; }
    void DownSetMaxEP(int value){ maxEP -= value; }
```

I must be missing something in the way things should be designed. In C# the property would be access like a field. however in C++ I have to do functions which work differently when accessed from other objects.

I guess i could do:

```
public:
    int MaxHP;
```

But that feels like I am sort of defeating the purpose. So my question is, Am i doing this right or is there a better, proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating separate getter and setter functions, you can have a function which returns a reference which can be used either way:

```
public:   
    int &max_hp() { return maxHP; }
```

Unlike just delaring maxHP public, this allows you to place a breakpoint to see when the variable is accessed, and if you later want to add conditions or logging you can do so without changing your class interface.

Comment: You probably want to provide the const version too. `const int& max_hp() const { return maxHP; }`. Otherwise you can't work on const objects. (Some would prefer to return a plain `int` in the const case - in 99% of cases it will make no difference)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I guess I'm not allowed to upvote yet. sorry.

Comment: This is a very solid answer...  in fact Scala emulates this very closely.  We're taught public fields are bad and tend to conflate this with difficult enough method names (get_ and set_) so as to make it look like fields are less public.  But every benefit I can name is wrapped up in this, however *yes definitely* you need the `const` version, C++ is like that.

Comment: So I've tested this and it works great. I should mention however, that I wont be using it with `const` for now. As it prevents me from setting the value from other objects with ease. (Unless I missed something).

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist in C/C++.  You could easily argue that it's a defect to be missing but not all languages are equal.  The one thing Java has that C# doesn't is singleton object-like enums.  It's otherwise, IMO, a bit of a dated language, but it still has one solid feature that's missing in C#.

So what I'm saying is, when you run into these things, often you do find a genuine weakness or a design flaw.  It's good to ask if you're just missing something (hence my upvote) but as you learn what strengths and weaknesses different languages have, you'll learn which languages are good for which jobs and perhaps be effective at writing DSLs or language extensions earlier in your career than later.

Comment: I understood this much already. However I felt like my current way of addressing this issue was just not the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of getters and setters functions in C++, I have written a simple macro that gets and sets most of data types that I use in my software. Templates also can be useful for that. 
For example

```
#define GET_BOOL(name) bool is##name() const {return name##_;}
#define SET_BOOL(name) void set##name(bool name) {name##_ = name;}
#define GET_SET_BOOL(name) GET_BOOL(name) SET_BOOL(name)
```

Comment: I'd make type another macro argument

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ does not support anything like this by default, however it is commonplace to have functions such as `int getHP()` and `void setHP(int)` but there is kind of an operator 'hack' to make it function pretty close to how c#'s get/set works. But the code to work around this is very messy and can cause many bugs.

Example (2nd post): http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?459696-GET-SET-in-C